# Change a Button IsEnabled state through DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, triggers

I'm trying to change the IsEnabled state of a button based on a TextBox.TextChanged event or a ComboBox.SelectionChanged event. I was trying to do this with events but the enabled state was being changed by the data being loaded. I'm populating a WPF UIElement Grid with Text Boxes and Combo Boxes. The grid is being populated via ItemSource of a List.

What I'm looking for is the editor containing the grid to be populated with data and the Apply buttons enabled state to be set to false until the user changes the data of a text box or combo box. At that time the DataTrigger should fire and change the btnApply.IsEnabled to true. I wasn't sure what to put for the Value of the events but "True" just didn't seem to be correct and True and HasChanged didn't work.

I'm open to different approaches other than a DataTrigger provided the IsEnabled is false be default when the control is presented to the user.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="tbChanged" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TextBox.TextChanged}" Value="HasChanged">
          <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ComboBox.SelectionChanged}" Value="HasChanged">
          <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Button x:Name="btnApply" Content="Apply" Height="22" Width="50" Margin="5,5,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" Click="btnApply_Click" Style="{StaticResource tbChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These triggers are not suitable for this, they are either active or inactive, meaning that they have a timeline while events do not. You could use Interactivity from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en) though, which has an `EventTrigger` which can call a `ChangePropertyAction`, e.g.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

```xml
<TextBox Name="myTextBox" />
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox" />
<Button IsEnabled="False" Content="Test">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger SourceName="myTextBox" EventName="TextChanged">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger SourceName="myComboBox" EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

There are also native `EventTriggers` but they are very restricted and you will probably not be able to get this done using them.

Comment: Thank you for the response H.B. - I'm concerned about the "SourceName" as I have several Text boxes and combo boxes that need to be able to change the buttons IsEnabled state. It's not as easy as a single text or combo box. There are about 50 or more text boxes and about 25 combo boxes. So I"m looking for a more generic setup for the event trapping. Are there more generic Event Triggers where I don't have to define the Source by name?

Comment: @GAR8: There is not as far as i know. You could inverse the triggers to be on the source objects though, setting the button property from there, however using these triggers in a style is very difficult so it won't be easy. (Further that sounds like a horrible UI)

Comment: HB-lol I agree the UI is awful there are three tabs with grids in each tab. The first tab alone has a grid displaying table attributes with 47 fields. The goal was to get the events to trigger through all three tabs. I really need a solid property grid to help clean this up. Also, I believe the Blend ref's require .Net 4. I'm restricted to .Net 3.5. I'll revert back to trying events again. Thank you for your interest. G